# How to rewrite differential partial equation with constant coefficients

Tags: calculus, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $$\frac{\partial^2U}{\partial x \partial y}, \frac{\partial^2U}{\partial y \partial x}$$ continuous. Considerer

$$a\frac{\partial^2U}{\partial x^2}+2b\frac{\partial^2U}{\partial x \partial y}+c\frac{\partial^2U}{\partial x^2}= 0. \hspace{1cm}{(1)}$$

for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$. Such that $ac - b^2 > 0$. Show this equation can be write like:

$$\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial s^2}+\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2}=0\hspace{2cm}{(2)}$$

if $$t= \frac{bx-ay}{\sqrt{ac-b^2}}, s= x$$

---

I've tried to start from (2) using partial derivatives, but I don't know how to start and how to use the fact that partial derivatives are continuous.

Comment: Did you take a look at my answer? If you're happy with it, you're more than welcome to accept and upvote it.

Comment: I'm sorry, your answer looks perfect to me, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the chain-rule for multivariable functions, we compute
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial U}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial U}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial U}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial x} 
= \frac{\partial U}{\partial s} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{ac-b^2}}\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}.
\end{align*}
Similarly, we compute
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial U}{\partial y} &= - \frac{a}{\sqrt{ac-b^2}}\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}, \\
\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x^2} &= \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial s^2} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{ac-b^2}}\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t\partial s} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{ac-b^2}}\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial s\partial t} + \frac{b^2}{ac-b^2}\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2}, \\
\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial y \partial x} &= -\frac{a}{\sqrt{ac-b^2}}\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t\partial s} - \frac{ab}{ac-b^2}\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2}, \\
\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x \partial y} &= -\frac{a}{\sqrt{ac-b^2}}\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial s\partial t} - \frac{ab}{ac-b^2}\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2}, \\
\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial y^2} &= \frac{a^2}{ac-b^2} \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2}.
\end{align*}
As by assumption $\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial^ 2U}{\partial y\partial y}$ are continuous, we may use Schwarz's theorem to conclude that both mixed partial derivatives are in fact equal, and hence also $\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial s\partial t}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t\partial s}$. Plugging the above formulas into the PDE yields
\begin{align*}
0 &= a\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial^2 x} + 2b\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x\partial y} + c\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial^2 y} \\
&= a \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial s^2} + \frac{2ab}{\sqrt{ac-b^2}}\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial s\partial t} + \frac{ab^2}{ac-b^2}\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2} - \frac{2ab}{\sqrt{ac-b^2}}\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t\partial s} - \frac{2ab^2}{ac-b^2} \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2} + \frac{ac^2}{ac-b^2} \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2} \\
&= a \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2} + \left[\frac{ab^2-2ab^2+ac^2}{ac-b^2}\right]\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2} \\
&= a\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial s^2} + a\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2}.
\end{align*}
Since $ac-b^2 > 0$, we have $a\neq 0$ and may divide by $a$ and obtain (2).